# what do you call a date/time with a T in the middle (2008-09-18T00:00:00)?

Tags: datetime

If you have a date like '2008-09-18T00:00:00' does it have a name? UTC? Something like that? Surprisingly hard to google for this...

Comment: A t-date? Sorry, couldn't ressist...

Comment: The joke you meant to use was T-time, I'm sure. T-date? I don't get it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That is a combined date/time representation as defined by [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It often has a timezone/offset appended to it, e.g. `2008-09-18T00:00:00Z` would denote UTC time.

Comment: Does it have a default timezone (no timezone appended)? UTC probably?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like RFC 3339.

Answer (score 2):

ISO 8601 is also relevant: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Wow... beat me by 6 seconds... +1

Answer (score 1):

Technically, that is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but Google refer to this simply as the "ISO date format" on [this support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035), as do a lot of other people (including me) seeing as it's a very popular standard. It's the top result if you google "iso date format".

Answer (score 0):

Also might be [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).