# Which kind of date format is this and how to convert it into JavaScript date?

Tags: php, javascript, date

Does this date format have any particular name and/or is it used in any particular programming language?

```
2012-11-28T12:52:22+0000
```

I need to convert this into JavaScript or PHP date, possibly without using string concatenation.

Kind of what somebody did here: [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Does any of these 2 programming languages have any pre-made function to do so?

Comment: same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002891/what-do-you-call-a-date-time-with-a-t-in-the-middle-2008-09-18t000000

Comment: well, not exactly the same if you read the answers they're posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601) date, which is becoming very common on the web.

It is an interoperability format, supported by many frameworks, and was added to [PHP in version 5.1.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

In JavaScript, it is supported by the [Date.toISOString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) method, and libraries such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - among others.

You can construct a JavaScript `Date` from an ISO string using its constructor:

```
var date = new Date('2012-11-28T12:52:22+0000');
```

Be aware that JavaScript is notoriously bad with dates.  It only understands dates from a local perspective, or from UTC.  Any offset you provide will be merged into the date.  That is being worked on in Moment.js. [see here](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/611).

Comment: so I have to use an external library for JavaScript. I didn't think about that... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

PHP handles this easily with the DateTime class:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-11-28T12:52:22+0000');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rGdCfI)

[`format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) accepts the same parameters as [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) so you can format it into any format you need.

**Reference**

- [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called an ISO-8601 date. With PHP you generate it with `date('c')` and with JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date('2012-11-28T12:52:22+0000');
date.toISOString();
```

As you can see, the argument to Date() can be just such a string.